# Set Layout as per every screen size of device in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

My app has an image in background and I want to adjust buttons size and position as per the image size. Image size change as per the device screen size.

I want to do it in XML layout file or using coding.
Please help me......

Thanks ion advance....

I am using android 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help you to set Layout that you can do it in xml itself

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Take a look on this...

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: but there are no of mobiles or tablet with variety of screen size.How can I do it for them?